# Word for "he signed up for this work for his resume without intending to do it"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to write a paper where I point out that a certain type of work is taken on more by people who want to do it for resume building and thus do not do the work well, when the focus should be on selecting for people who want to do the job. However, it would be crass to say this specific line, so the best I have right now is just listing the positive side ("we should focus on those who genuinely would like to work in this lab"), but this does not convey the point as strongly as the negative ("The reason we are not able to get work done in the lab is because we are hiring people who only want the resume line item and do not want to do work").

Is there a word I can use for the negative side (ex. "We need to implement X filter to filter out ____ people")? I thought about using "inauthentic" or "insincere", but both have more of a hand-wavy philosophy connotation than I would like.

Comment: *"to implement X filter"* is not idiomatic at all. "Chancer" works as a negative noun: MW = a scheming opportunist; Oxford Languages via Google = a person who exploits any opportunity to further their own ends; Cambridge = a person who is always trying to get an advantage for himself or herself, especially by taking risks.

Comment: I have seen the phrase "résumé padders" used in place of "_______ people" in similar contexts.